# meteorjs - admin users like django

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

someone know one package or one tutorial to make admin users like django?
i'd like create superuser with terminal and on admin pages create users but i'd like create personalization users with schema of collection2. I 'd like remove create user of acconts-password and only superuser can create users.

Answer (score 1):

What about `houston:admin`?

> Houston is a zero-config Meteor Admin, modeled after Django Admin

https://github.com/gterrono/houston

I have not tried it, but sounds like it's what you are looking for

Comment: i tried but i don't like. you can't mangae users, only your collections. I use collection2 Do you Know how make a schema to use as user that can login?